# How do I make a line and add equidistant points in Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, line, distance, equals, points

I want to add a line and add points in Tkinter.
It has to be like an x-axis without a y-axis.

Comment: What did you try? What is the problem that made you stuck? Please post a code that you already have.

Comment: This question can be answered by simply reading available documentation. It's not clear what sort of help you need.

Comment: I have been able to create a line, how do I create dots with the labeling of 0,1,2,3,4,5, and so on? Just like the x-axis has dots and labeling. Kindly help me out?

Answer (score 0):

C.create_line(x1,x2,y1,y2)

To create the dots you need to draw dots the same amount of pixels from the ends of the line.